# Clarification of an answer about CT sensors and diagram

Tags: ac, dc

Hi I have found a perfect [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215306/capacitor-for-current-transformer-measurement-circuit) that clears the purpose of the parts in the schematic.
So two resistors and arduino 5v source adds up to the negative side of the AC voltage.

Is there any "special" name or this kind of circuit where you add  aditional "control" voltage?
How can DC voltage be added to AC?

Answer (score 0):

Bias, offset, and reference are all good terms for the function of that circuit.  The sense coil is biased in the middle of the ADC range.  A DC reference/offset is applied to the sense coil.  Could also be considered a virtual ground as is used with single-supply analog circuit design.