# How do I calculate a CT output curve when measuring through an op amp and diode?

Tags: current-transformer

I am designing a circuit that uses a CT sensor to measure the current in a 240 VAC line.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fneXCj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have observed the following relationship between current (on the primary) and voltage (on the CT sensor).

[image: Graph]

The relationship is non-linear. Is there an equation to calculate the curve, so that I can map current to mV? I intend to run some code on an MCU.

Edit: I plotted some new data with a slightly different test setup, and found similar results. The curve seems like a Bezier from 0 A to 3 A, but from 3 A onward, it appears linear.

It seems that I could use a Bezier for less than 3 A, and linear for above 3 A. I imagine that something else happens with much more current (the CT is rated 100 A at 1V), but 5 A is about the most I can do at my bench.

[image: Graph]

Edit: Yes, I was missing the burden resistor in the schematic (fixed), and the part comes with one built in. CT datasheet: [SCT013-000V](https://bc-robotics.com/datasheets/yhdc.pdf)

Comment: The schematic looks wrong. There must be a resistor across secondary side.

Comment: Can you put a datasheet or at least a manufacturer part number of the current transformer? And @Chupacabras, I came to say the same thing *(the necessity of a burden resistor)* but the OP says it outputs 1V for 100A, so it appears to be a current-to-voltage converter, not an ordinary current transformer. Maybe something like 10mV/A current probes to be used with oscilloscopes.

Comment: Genuine TL081 has offset voltage in millivolts. After multiplication by 10 you get tens of millivolts. That attributes to the imprecision.

Comment: @Chupacabras Fixed schematic. Are you saying the current to sensor voltage relationship should be linear?

Comment: I'm saying you are using improper opamp. Use something with much lower input offset voltage, say OP07. Next thing what adds to nonlinearity is the diode D1.

Comment: Thanks, would 358N work? Didn't think about diode forward voltage. Is it better to bias the voltage and take samples with the MCU rather than using an op amp? e.g. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215306/capacitor-for-current-transformer-measurement-circuit

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You need to consider the input offset error of the op amp because you are trying to measure millivolts but the zero-error is already in the range. So you have two options: 1) Use an op amp with the lowest offset error (somewhere up to a few tens of uV), or 2) Use whichever op amp you want, but run a zero-calibration and make calculations during measurement accordingly. Also if you want to compensate the error that diode's forward drop brings then you may want to use an op amp precision rectifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks:

- Using a diode should be non-linear ... and temperature dependent.
  Remember you measure "tenth" mV, and diode "has" coefficient of -2 mV/°C.
- > ... but 5 A is about the most I can do at my bench.

No worries about this.
Just **do 10 turns inside the CT** ... and now **you have 50 A measured** ... **with 5 A**.

- If you want a "linear" function, use a "super-diode" ...
  or a synchronized sampling on "peak" voltage.

Example of "hardware "synchronized" sampling ...

[image]

Note that this can be done also with software.